Error connecting to the database: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myJPAUnit
I have this error in my Jakarta EE app when I want to connect to PostgreSQL:

Error connecting to the database: No Persistence provider for EntityManager named myJPAUnit

This is my persistence.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence xmlns="https://jakarta.ee/xml/ns/persistence" version="3.0">
    <persistence-unit name="myJPAUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
        <properties>
            <!-- JDBC Database connection settings -->
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/jeeCrud"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.user" value="jeeCrud"/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.password" value=""/>
            <property name="jakarta.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>

            <!-- Hibernate settings -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>


and this is pom.xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.orm</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>6.2.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.7.3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

How can I resolve this problem?

(1) add your entiry class or model class  <persistence-unit name="myJPAUnit" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">         <class>com.example.model.Person</class>, (2)
remove <provider>org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider</provider>
